# Cordova Capture Image in Background Base64

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

How to capture image in background continuously with Cordova and getting the result as base64?

I want to capture image continuosly without opening default camera apps or other camera apps, it's like i'm making custom camera apps itself.

I need it to be able to output as base64 and clean the memory of previous output to prevent memory overflow.

I need this to make custom camera capture.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "in background"? fwif, all the plugins i've tried to use to grab stills for a motion detector app inevitably crash the app after a few minutes.

Comment: can you explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: What does it even mean to capture image in the background continuously? Are you really trying to continuously take pictures and save them? This will cause your app to crash, at best. You must explain your question better.

Comment: I want to capture image continuosly without opening default camera apps or other camera apps, it's like i'm making custom camera apps itself.

I need it to be able to output as base64 and clean the memory of previous output to prevent memory overflow.

@dandavis

Comment: Notify @ThomCunningham

Comment: From a quick Google search, I found this plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#module_Camera.DestinationType - it seems to have most of what you're looking for. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ThomCunningham it will open default camera apps, i want it to take picture without opening other apps.